# how can I count a number from a string

Tags: c#

```
string val = "4 12 441 662 2234 441 441";
```

I'm trying to count duplicates after the counting the duplicates are getting removed. Currently I'm stuck and can't go forward.

I want this output `4 12 662 2234 3x 441`

Comment: Given the answer you marked as correct, I think you should change your required output to be the same as the answer you marked as correct - otherwise your requirements don't match that answer's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why Regular Expression at all?

```
string val = "4 12 441 662 2234 441 441";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", val.Split(' ').GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Count() > 1 ? $"{x.Count()}x {x.Key}" : x.Key)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Linq like so:

```
string val = "4 12 441 662 2234 441 441";

var groupedValues = 
    val.Split(' ')
   .GroupBy(x => x)
   .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
   .Select(g => g.Count() > 1 ? g.Count() + "x " + g.Key : g.Key);

var result = string.Join(' ', groupedValues);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 4 12 662 2234 3x 441
```

It would be slightly more efficient to write the Linq as follows to avoid recalculating `Count()` twice:

```
var groupedValues = 
    val.Split(' ')
   .GroupBy(x => x)
   .Select(f => (count: f.Count(), value: f.Key))
   .OrderBy(g => g.count)
   .Select(h => h.count > 1 ? h.count + "x " + h.value : h.value);
```

Note the `.OrderBy()` which ensures that the repeated values go at the end of the output, as per your original requirement.

Comment: Almost identical :)

Comment: Almost - but yours needs an `OrderBy()` to output the results with the duplicates at the end (as per the OP's requirement).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of digits in a string by using a  space delimiter to separate them after that it is much easier to find out the duplicates in an array.

Comment: the count is not the problem `Regex.Matches(val, l).Count` is counting it without problems. but I want that the duplicates getting removed and my string should be `"4 12 662 2234 3x 441"`

Comment: You can form another string in which you can remove the first occurrence of digit by your original string.@newcoma

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq.

1. split String into parts.
2. Group all the same with the `GroupBy` Expression. (Grouping has a`Key` and a `List` containing all the
   Matches)
3. Aggregate this takes a starting String and a expression how to handle ongoing elements

```cs
string val = "4 12 441 662 2234 441 441";
                
var splitted = val.Split(' ');

var resultString = splitted.ToList()
   .GroupBy(el => el)
   .Select(grouping => grouping.Count() + "x " + grouping.Key)
   .Aggregate("", (s1, s2) => s1 + s2 + ", ");

   Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Comment: This is going to put a "1x" in front of items that are not duplicates.  Also the OP didn't want the values comma separated (and this will add an extra comma at the end).  Finally doing string concatenation in `Aggregate` is the same as doing it in a loop which is a bad idea, it's better to use Linq to create the string values and then use `string.Join` to join them together.

Answer (score 1):

Using `LINQ`

```
string val = "4 12 441 662 2234 441 441";
var result = val.Split(" ")
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Count())
                .OrderBy(z => z.Value)
                .Select(x=> x.Value == 1 ? $"{x.Key}" : $"{x.Value}x {x.Key}")
                .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));
```

OUTPUT

```
4 12 662 2234 3x 441
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

First of all get your `string` as `List`

```cs
string val = "4 12 441 662 2234 441 441";
var list = val.Split(' ').ToList();
```

Then get the values repeated and store into a object with `Value` and `Count`:

```cs
var query = list.GroupBy(r => r)
            .Select(grp => new
            {
              Value = grp.Key,
              Count = grp.Count()
            });
```

Now you have something like `[{Value: X, Count: X}, {...}, {...} ... ]`

And after that iterate over this list you can create a new `string` to output

```cs
var str = "";
foreach (var item in query)
{
  if(item.Count > 1)
  {
    str += item.Count+"x ";
  }
  str+=item.Value+" ";
}
Console.WriteLine("str = "+str);
```

The output is: `str = 4 12 3x 441 662 2234`

Comment: String concatenation in a loop is a bad idea.  It's better to use `StringBuilder`, or in this case you can easily use `string.Join` instead of a loop.